# Python: Create dictionary from table on file with variable columns

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a file `data.txt` looking like

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

Running the code

```
file = open('data.txt')
foo = dict([line.split() for line in file])
```

Creates a dictionary

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

I find this quite elegant. Suppose I have now a file `data_vec.txt` looking like

```
a 1 2 3
b 2
c 3
```

I would like to do the same as above to have in output the dictionary

```
    {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

The code above won't work with lines of different length. I can obtain the desired output by writing

```
file = open('data_vec.txt')
foo = dict()
for line in file:
        split_line = line.split()
        foo[split_line[0]] = split_line[1:]
```

but I don't think it's as elegant a solution as the one above for the two-column file. Is there anything more *pythonic* that could be done?

**Edit**
Would

```
foo = dict([[line.split()[0], line.split()[1:]] for line in file])
```

be acceptable? If not, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [extended iterable unpacking](https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/) with a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-dictionary-comprehension):

```
with open('data_vec.txt') as file:
    foo = {key: values for key, *values in map(str.split, file)}
    print(foo)
```

**Output**

```
{'a': ['1', '2', '3'], 'b': ['2'], 'c': ['3']}
```